# preg_match for Specific URL Structure

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to grab parts of a URL to create an embed code. I have the following URL structure:

`http://www.mtv.com/videos/foster-the-people/761507/houdini.jhtml#id=1518072&amp;vid=761507`

I need to use `preg_match` to break the URL into a few pieces. Ideally, I want to test for the structure of the URL and get the numeric values from the URL. Ultimately, I would like an array in the following form after the `preg_match`:

```
Array (
    0 => 761507
    1 => 1518072
    2 => 761507
)
```

Note that "foster-the-people" and "houdini" are dynamic elements that can contain letters, numbers and "-" and will change from URL to URL.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :** (UPDATED)

```
http:\/\/www\.mtv\.com\/videos\/.*?\/([0-9]+)\/.*?id=([0-9]+)&vid=([0-9]+)
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?30qo4

---

**Code :**

```
<?php
    $subject = "http://www.mtv.com/videos/foster-the-people/761507/houdini.jhtml#id=1518072&vid=761507";
    $pattern = '/http:\/\/www\.mtv\.com\/videos\/.*?\/([0-9]+)\/.*?id=([0-9]+)&vid=([0-9]+)/';
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.mtv.com/videos/foster-the-people/761507/houdini.jhtml#id=1518072&vid=761507
    [1] => 761507
    [2] => 1518072
    [3] => 761507
)
```

---

**Hint :** The elements you need are `$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]` and `$matches[3]`

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is a great start. I also need to match the rest of the structure. I need to make sure this is an MTV video link by looking at the rest of the structure.

Comment: @Sardine So, you mean you want to make sure it's something starting with `http://www.mtv.com/videos/`?

Comment: Dr. Kameleon, you are a magical doctor indeed! Thank you for your help! Works like a charm!

Comment: One quick follow-up. How can I match `&` and `&amp;` prior to vid?

Comment: Look at this one : http://regexr.com?30qog . By using `http:\/\/www\.mtv\.com\/videos\/.*?\/([0-9]+)\/.*?id=([0-9]+)(&|&amp;)vid=([0-9]+)`, you can match either **`&`** OR **`&amp;`**. (before `vid=` that is...)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) first to break your URL into individual components and then if needed use preg_match to get individual sub-items from `$urlarr['query']` where `$urlarr` is return value of parse_url.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Normally, I would do just that (primarily because my regex skills are lacking), but in this case, I'm utilizing an API that requires me to specify a regex match. Thanks for your thoughts!